# .Jar file in JS

Tags: java, javascript, jar

does any knows how to access .jar file in JS. I have created class in Java and imported as a jar file and I want to access that class from JS file.

"Hi Guys, i thankful to all of you. I tried to list files from a folder using JS in Firefox XUL but I couldn't then i decided to do it with JAVA in JS. I would be happy if i find one example either with JS or Java in JS to list folder files."

Thanking u guys.

karthik

One of my tutor had done it and here is the code but i couldn't understand! I'm sure he called the jar files from the same project folder where exactly all the JS and XUL files are located.

```
// This function will be called to give the necessary privileges to your JAR files

function policyAdd (loader, urls) {
    //alert("debut charge java");
    try {
        //If have trouble with the policy try changing it to 
        //edu.mit.simile.javaFirefoxExtensionUtils.URLSetPolicy        
        var str = 'edu.mit.simile.javaFirefoxExtensionUtils.URLSetPolicy';
        var policyClass = java.lang.Class.forName(
               str,
               true,
               loader
        );
        var policy = policyClass.newInstance();
        policy.setOuterPolicy(java.security.Policy.getPolicy());
        java.security.Policy.setPolicy(policy);
        policy.addPermission(new java.security.AllPermission());
        for (var j=0; j < urls.length; j++) {
            policy.addURL(urls[j]);
        }
    }catch(e) {
       alert(e+'::'+e.lineNumber);
    }
}

//Get extension folder installation path...
var extensionPath = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/extensions/manager;1"].
            getService(Components.interfaces.nsIExtensionManager).
            getInstallLocation("pde@ghorbel.com"). // guid of extension
            getItemLocation("pde@ghorbel.com");

// Get path to the JAR files (the following assumes your JARs are within a
// directory called "java" at the root of your extension's folder hierarchy)
// You must add this utilities (classloader) JAR to give your extension full privileges
var classLoaderJarpath = "file:///" + extensionPath.path.replace(/\\/g,"/") + "/java/javaFirefoxExtensionUtils.jar";
// Add the paths for all the other JAR files that you will be using
var myJarpath = "file:///" + extensionPath.path.replace(/\\/g,"/") +
"/java/encryption.jar"; // seems you don't actually have to replace the backslashes as they work as well

var urlArray = []; // Build a regular JavaScript array (LiveConnect will auto-convert to a Java array)
urlArray[0] = new java.net.URL(myJarpath);
urlArray[1] = new java.net.URL(classLoaderJarpath);
var cl = java.net.URLClassLoader.newInstance(urlArray);

//Set security policies using the above policyAdd() function
policyAdd(cl, urlArray);

/*


//loading Encryption Class
var myClass = cl.loadClass('Encryption'); // use the same loader from above
var encryptionObj = myClass.newInstance();
//var res = encryptionObj.encrypt("test message to crypt"); // Pass whatever arguments you need (they'll be auto-converted to Java form, taking into account the LiveConnect conversion rules)

*/
```

Comment: the 'java' in 'javascript' is not related to the 'java' in 'java'. i.e. this can't be done

Comment: @ampersand - in some contexts, it can.

Comment: @Stephen, from the OP's one-liner, I was under the impression that he wanted to use it in the normal sense of defining instances using the class. Of course, OP has now provide more context for his one-liner, so my comments have become irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to look at LiveConnect which allows Javascript to call Java and vice versa in a web browser.

References:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LiveConnect
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/LiveConnect
- http://jdk6.java.net/plugin2/liveconnect/

---

Whether this will allow you to do what you want (access the file system on the user's machine) is another question.  That will depend on whether the Java is distributed as a signed JAR ... and the user / browser accepts the signature.  If the JAR is not signed then the Java code will be treated as untrusted code, and executed in a sandbox that (by default) prevents it from accessing the local filesystem.

Comment: Hi Guys, i thankful to all of you. I tried to list files from a folder using JS in Firefox XUL but I couldn't then i decided to do it with JAVA in JS. I would be happy if i find one example either with JS or Java in JS to list folder files.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but currently no such functionality is developed so you can not access jar file in javascript.

What you can do is fire an AJAX request in javascript and in servlet use that jar for processing and return desired result and that result will be accessible in javascript.

---

**Edit**

In servlet:

```
File file = new File("/folderName");
File[] files;
if(file.isDirectory()){
    files = file.listFiles();
    for(File fl : files){
        out.print(fl.getName()+",");
}
```

In javascript:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", urlToServlet, false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Now in js in `xmlhttp.responseText` you will get list of files in a folder. You can parse it and display the list as per your need.

Comment: Thanks Harry. You know i'm working on a Firefox XUL extension i have to work with JS and Java. In fact, i want to list files from a folder using JS but i couldn't then I decided do it with java. Now as i said before i have to link .jar file with JS.

Comment: @katthikin: I think this should work in FF cause I have already used it in some of my project.

Comment: Oh nice. Then could you give me some more detailed information that how you link all these files.

Comment: @Karthikin: what you mean by linking files? making a link to download file?

Comment: I meant, i need some more detailed information in your code! Do i have to create a servlet file and link with JS? am i correct?

Comment: @Karthikin: Yes you have to create a servlet file put the code that is under "in Servlet" in any on of doGet/doPost method of request. Then put its in url in "urlToServlet" in js code and accrodingly update the POST/GET method in `xmlhttp.open("POST", urlToServlet, false);`.

Comment: Harry, i got it. If it possible could you give me a detailed code example to read files in a folder using servlet and JS. Thank U.

Comment: @Kathikin: The above code is running code and it will return list of file names in js from servlet. Just copy paste code at proper location.

Comment: HI Harry,var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "file://D:/filesFinder.java", false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
alert('hi');
objXMLDoc = objxmlhttp.responseText; //Here is a problem. Could u tell where am i wrong?

Comment: you don't have to write java file path there just use it's name as you define in web.xml file.

Comment: Here i'm not using any web.xml file. In fact, i'm trying to load a list of files from a folder in Xul Menu list. So i just need to list my xml files in the xul menu list from local folder.

Comment: js will not communicate with normal java file you need servlet and there for a web.xml file.

Comment: you should take some ajax and servlet tutorial before going ahead.

Answer (score 2):

Create a trusted applet to use the existing Jars.  JavaScript can communicate with (get data from/send dato to) Java applets.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an applet to your page, doesn't have to have any UI aspect to it, you can then get hold of the applet via the DOM.  Once you have that you can call methods on it, so put your api in the applet class of provide a getter to to an object that provides the functionality you want and call that.

Comment: Hi Guys, i thankful to all of you. I tried to list files from a folder using JS in Firefox XUL but I couldn't  then i decided to do it with JAVA in JS. I would be happy if i find one example either with JS or Java in JS to list folder files.

Comment: If you try doing this with an applet it will need to be signed and the user will have to accept it before it will be allowed to access the filesystem.  I've not done much with xul, but I'd have thought there would have been something to get at the file system without having to resort to an applet.