# Using a .jar file in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, web-applications, backend

I am working on a web app that is using the ReactJS library on the front end and a .jar file that I need to use for my backend. Is it possible to call the Java functions using javascript without having to use Rest API? I believe that java applets are already deprecated and probably not viable.

My apologies if my question is unclear as I am quite new to the community. Please let me know if further clarifications are required.

Edit: What I meant is that I want to call the java methods/classes directly from the .jar file using javascript so that I don't need to write more backend code in javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.Jar file in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907993/jar-file-in-js)

Comment: REST API is not a thing you use in your JavaScript. It's software architectural style that defines a set of constraints to be used for creating Web services. It's guidelines on how to structure your API. So javascript doesn't cares whether your API is RESTful or something else.